# TypeError: setBodyPart is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick

I have declared setBodyPart state which is passed and used as a prop in another file which shows error that setBodyPart is not a function.

````
       const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([]);
       const [bodyPart, setBodyPart] = useState("all");
   
       return (
         <Box>
           <HeroBanner />
           <SearchExercises
           setExercises={setExercises}
           bodyPart={bodyPart}
           setBodyPart={setBodyPart}
         />
         <Exercises
           setExercises={setExercises}
           exercises={exercises}
           bodyPart={bodyPart}
         />
          </Box>
        );
      };
        
       const BodyPart = ({ item, setBodyPart, bodyPart }) => {
        return (
        <Stack
         
         onClick={() => {
          setBodyPart(item);
           window.scrollTo({ top: 1800, left: 100, behavior: "smooth" 
      });
         }}
       >
   ```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Show how the props are being passed.

Comment: Show where you use that component. Are you passing the setBodyPart prop?

Comment: Yes i am using it as prop

Comment: Dude, if in console `TypeError: setBodyPart is not a function`, then `setBodyPart is not a function`. Either you provide a minimal reproducible example, or it will remain so.

Answer (score 0):

The error is solved and there are 2 ways of it.

1st Way is to not write the code in different files write it in 1 file only like `Home.js` or any.

2nd Way is to create both the files in same folder only because the state variable which is declared in one file will be available in another file of the same folder.